# Assigning to a dynamically created vector

Tags: r

How do I assign to a dynamically created vector?

```
master<-c("bob","ed","frank")
d<-seq(1:10)
for (i in 1:length(master)){
  assign(master[i], d )
}

eval(parse(text=master[2]))[2] # I can access the data

#   but how can I assign to it THIS RETURNS AN ERROR     #######################
eval(parse(text=master[2]))[2]<- 900
```

Comment: Use `get(master[2])`. Using eval is generally seen as evidence of lack of knowlege but if you really want to do so then try: `eval(as.name(master[2]))`. There is a division between data-objects and language-objects. So `get` and `as.name` can be thought of as "promoting" the status of a character object to a language object.

Comment: @Bonded get(master[2])[2]<-900 returns an ERROR

Comment: Couldn't figure out the desired result. If you want to do assignment than why not use  .... `assign`?

Comment: @Bonded assign(eval(as.name(master[2]))[2],5)  ERRORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I'll post this code but only because I was asked to:

```
> eval(parse(text=paste0( master[2], "[2]<- 900" ) ) )
> ed
 [1]   1 900   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

It's generally considered bad practice to use such a method. You need to build the expression" `ed[2] < 100`. Using `paste0` lets you evaluate master[2] as `'ed'` which is then concatenated with the rest of the characters before passing to `parse` for convert to a language object. This would be more in keeping with what is considered better practice:

```
master<-c("bob","ed","frank")
d<-seq(1:10)
mlist <- setNames( lapply(seq_along(master), function(x) {d} ), master)
```

So changing the second value of the second item  with `<-`:

```
> mlist[[2]][2] <- 900
> mlist[['ed']]
 [1]   1 900   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

Comment: what would be the best practice?